# Botón Aceptar en Cookies Webdriver Selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scraping, cookies

Tengo el código de un banner que me sale para aceptar cookies y mi programa en Java no encuentra el botón Aceptar, me da error. Estoy usando Selenium Webdriver para automatizar una página pero me sale ese anuncio de coockie y no puedo pasar de ahí. Es como si no existiera. Quizá es porque hay un ==$0 en esa parte de código.

He optado por varias opciones para hacer scraping de ese boton, pero ninguna es válida,

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[normalize-space()='Aceptar']")).click();`
`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='cc-nb-okagree']")).click();`

cual es la solución?

envío imagen del código a captar
[image: foto del código]

Comment: El `== $0` no tiene nada que ver. Eso es algo propio de Chrome. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36999842/13419694

Comment: ¿Estás usando alguna configuración de Chrome? ¿Quizá está corriendo en modo `headless`? ¿Puedes compartir la página? Así los interesados en ayudarte podemos investigar a qué se debe.

Comment: no estoy corriendo en modo headless porque si así fuera no podría ver la página ....

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, si es una alerta puedes desde los capabilities omitirlas, si ese no es el caso puedes usar otra funcionalidad que es la siguiente https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.